# Gapi.client.drive.files.update() Returning error "Parse Error"

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

Working with the google api, and I have to sets of code that are essentially the same, but are producing different results.

Both simply take in a fileId and two parentId's, one to remove, and one to add with the google api. It's essentially a move operation for a file in google drive. The code that works, simply expects a signature of `(from, to, file) => {}` and the one that doesn't is being passed the fields in the callback of a Google Picker Call. ([Link to Picker API Docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#ViewId))

The first one returns a success and the second get's a response from the api stating there was a parse error, with little much else as to what could be causing the parse error.

## Examples:

### Working Example

```
moveFile = (from, to, file) => {
    return gapi.client.drive.files
        .update({
            addParents: to,
            removeParents: from,
            fileId: file,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            logger.log(funcname, `Moved File: ${file} from ${from} to ${to}.`);
            return res.result;
        });
};
```

### Non-Working Example

```
function folderSelectedCallback(folderData, fileData) {

    //folderData and fileData both have the same structure
    //{action: 'type of action', 
    //docs: [{Array Of Document Objects}],
    //viewToken: [Array of unused data]}

    //Docs Array Objects Structure (only used properties listed.)
    //{ id: 'string ID of the File',
    //parentId: 'string ID of the parent folder'}

    if (folderData.action === 'picked') {
        console.log('folderSelectedCallback(): called.');
        console.log('File Data: ', fileData);
        console.log('Folder Data: ', folderData);
        const files = fileData.docs;
        const folder = folderData.docs[0];

        console.log(files);
        console.log(folder);

        files.forEach((f) => {
            gapi.client.drive.files
                .update({
                    addParents: to,
                    removeParents: from,
                    fileId: file,
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(funcname, `Moved File: ${file} from ${from} to ${to}.`);
                    return res.result;
                }).catch(err => console.error(err));
        });
    }
}
```

Is there more information I need to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Working Final Example

```
function folderSelectedCallback(folderData, fileData) {
    if (folderData.action === 'picked') {
        console.log('folderSelectedCallback(): called.');
        console.log('File Data: ', fileData);
        console.log('Folder Data: ', folderData);
        const files = fileData.docs;
        const folder = folderData.docs[0];

        console.log(files);
        console.log(folder);

        files.forEach((f) => {

            const options = {
                addParents: folder.id,
                removeParents: (typeof f.parentId !== 'undefined') ? f.parentId : '',
                fileId: f.id
            };

            gapi.client
                .request({
                    path: `drive/v3/files/${options.fileId}`,
                    method: 'PATCH',
                    params: options,
                    body: options
                })
                .then((response) => console.log(response))
                .catch((err) => console.error(err));
        });
    }
}
```

For some reason using `gapi.client.request` in this manner works correctly.